# Error while using angular JS directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular JS and trying to use Directives.

Below is the code for directive :

```
app.directive('appInfo', function() { 
  return { 
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: { 
      info: '=' 
    }, 
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/appInfo.html' 
  }; 
});
```

Below is my main JS:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.apps = [
      {
        icon: 'img/move.jpg',
        title: 'MOVE',
        developer: 'MOVE, Inc.',
        price: 0.99,
        info: "move"
      }
    ]
}]);
```

Now, when i am trying to use this in html i am getting very bad error that ia ma unable to under stand :

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat = "app in apps">
    <app-info info="{{ app.info }}"></app-info>
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the error you cannot understand?

Comment: _getting very bad error that ia ma unable to under stand_ ........... what error?

Comment: Error: 

`[$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7B%20app.info%20%7D%7D&p4=%7B%20app.info%20%7D%7D`

Answer (score 1):

While passing data to angular directive, you don't need to use interpolation, pass the data directly like this:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat = "app in apps">
  <app-info info="app.info"></app-info>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This resolved the error but i am not able to see the app-info directive UI that is present in html file linked.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `{{}}` in ng-repeat.

```
 <app-info info="app.info"></app-info>
```

Comment: This resolved the error but i am not able to see the app-info directive UI that is present in html file linked.